# How to handle long AJAX requests - send a response but continue to work

Tags: c#, java, ajax, multithreading, jquery

We are sending in instruction sets from a browser into a multi-tier web app using jquery-ajax.  The first component (component A, written in C#) validates and persists the instructions into a database, and then calls the second component (component B, written in Java and also called via HTTP) which operates on the instructions after retrieving them from the same database.  The browser client just polls the rdbms table via component A after submitting the job, so it is effectively disconnected after sending in the request and doesn't wait for a response from component A.

What is the best way for the middle-tier (component A) to return a success message to the client acknowledging a successful submission of the task, but then still make the request to the task handler (component B) and releasing all of its resources?  Returning a response is a final action for the page so we'd have to do something in another thread before sending this back to the browser.

Another option we have considered is for this to happen in component B where the task handler sends back an immediate response to the middle tier acknowledging the request, but then continues on working in the background.  The only difference would be where we spawn the additional thread to do the work.

Any good ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: When I had a similar situation, I created one web service with two interfaces.  One would receive an instruction and start a thread processing that instruction.  The other would be able to poll the running thread using IPC and return the status of the instruction.  I would use ajax to submit to the first method and upon success would start a javascript timer that would fire off an ajax request every 5 seconds (or whatever your polling interval needs to be) to obtain the status and print it to the browser.

Comment: At one point in your request you had to spawn another thread to continue the work while still returning a message to the client.  How did you do that?

Comment: At the time, I was writing my server in perl, so I just fork'ed the server at that point in the program.  In .net, it would be easier to use a BackgroundWorker.  You can spawn it and let it run and use its ability to report progress to keep track of where each thread is at when the client queries status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we have done in situations like this is:

- Browser send instruction set to component A
- Component A validates instruction set
- Component A save instruction set to DB under new "tracking" ID `STATUS=PENDING`
- Component make request to component B to do the work
- "Threading" is in component B:

  - Component B starts background thread to do the work, first thing background thread does is update status of "tracking ID" to  `STATUS=RUNNING`
  - Component B main thread returns to success to component A
- Component A gets "started successfully" message from component B, so returns its own "started successfully" message back to the browser  along with the "tracking ID". At this stage component A is done with the request, all component A resources are free.
- Browser can make different call to component A to check status of "tracking ID" in the DB
- Meanwhile the background "thread" of component B is still doing the work, possibly recording progress against the "tracking ID"
- Component B completes work, updates status of "tracking ID" in DB, `STATUS=OK` or `STATUS=ERROR` and gives up all resources.

The advantage of all that is there is no waiting for the work to finish from you application's point of view. The actual work is done by a "background" thread, just as if you kicked it off with `nohup dothework &` in a shell. The key is using the DB to monitor the status of the "tracking ID".

Comment: OK, this seems to make the most sense.  Looks like I need to add a thread to my Java Servlet.  Out of curiosity, do you have any tips or good links that will help with spawning background threads from Servlets?

Comment: No sorry, don't have much java experience.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to handle this situation manually, by spawning threads. But one main problem you will face down the road (which I have faced in my programming experience) is that threads are a bit hard to maintain and have several disadvantages if not handled properly. First one is that the error handling capabilities are limited and you will have to have an external table (persisted one) or a global variable logging or catching all those errors. One more problem is the processing limit that the server can take. If you spawn too many threads in the background, the server processing limit and hence the database requests that it makes simultaneously will become a pain later.

The best solution to avoid is through any available backgrounding task framework. The advantage of them is that they will follow a producer/consumer queue pattern and will do all the tracking for you through a separate daemon process running in the background. But then the disadvantage here is the daemon process would still be vulnerable.

One more option is to integrate the Queueing or Messaging service like [Rabbit MQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html). This will not only scale but has a very good implementation available in different languages.

Comment: We considered implementing either MSMQ or WebLogic JMS, but both were shot down for political reasons.  Sigh - I agree that this is the best way to handle it.